# C# How to convert a struct type list into a string?

Tags: c#, string, list, unity-game-engine, casting

I am doing a game in Unity and need help with converting my struct list into a string. My codes below are put inside a class called, MonsterHandler.

```
public enum S_STATE
{
    S_IDLE,
    S_PATROL,
    S_ATTACK,
    NONE
}

public struct MONSTERS
{
    public string Name;
    public int Health;
    public int Damage;
    public S_STATE State;
};

public List<MONSTERS> monsterList= new List<MONSTERS>();

void Start()
{
   // add data into the monsterList
   // Debug.Log(monsterList.Count); // print out 5

   Debug.Log(monsterList.ToArray()); //printed out "MonsterHandler + MONSTERS"
   // i want to do something like this
   // "Monster_Zombie, 100, 20, S_IDLE, Monster_Donkey, 80, 30, S_IDLE,  Monster_Chicken, 120 , 10, IDLE,.."
}
}
```

Is there a way to cast my struct list into a string[], then convert into a string? Or there any other ways

Comment: what do you want printed?

Comment: @KeithNicholas i want to print out something like this

Comment: "Monster_Zombie, 100, 20, S_IDLE, Monster_Donkey, 80, 30, S_IDLE,  Monster_Chicken, 120 , 10, IDLE,.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `ToString` on Monster, but if you want flexibility in how things get displayed in different contexts then I'd keep how you render things separate from the model

```
Debug.Log(string.Join("\r\n",
     monsterList.Select(monster => $"{monster.Name}, {monster.Health}, whatever")
    .ToArray()));
```

using console...

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n",monsterList.Select(monster => $"{monster.Name} {monster.Health} {monster.Damage} {monster.State}").ToArray()));
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, but it only print out the first two monster data, I have a total of 5 monsters. @Keith Nicholas

Comment: should be nothing to limiting it to two,,,,   I just changed it to console and printed it out, and got 5,   debug.log may have issues \r\n, so maybe put | instead or something

Comment: Ah, | works! thanks alot :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd first rename the types (and enum values) to follow .NET naming conventions and to indicate that the struct represents a *single* monster.
It's unfortunate IMO that mutable structs are common in Unity, but I'll leave that part aside.

I'd next override `ToString()` in `Monster`. Assuming you can use C# 6 features, string interpolation makes this really simple.

Finally, to convert a list of monsters to a string, you'll want to use `string.Join`. The exact nature of the call will depend on what you have available - if you're still targeting .NET 3.5, it's slightly ugly. But you'd end up with something like:

```
public enum State
{
    None, // Idiomatically value 0 in .NET
    Idle,
    Patrol,
    Attack
}

public struct Monster
{
    public string Name;
    public int Health;
    public int Damage;
    public State State;

    // Adjust this as required
    public override string ToString() =>
        $"Name: {Name}; Health: {Health}; Damage: {Damage}; State: {State}";
}

public List<Monster> monsters = new List<Monster>();

void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", monsters.Select(m => m.ToString().ToArray());
}
```

Note that this is an expensive operation - you probably only want to do it when debugging. (I don't know whether calls to `Debug.Log` are conditional in Unity.)

In .NET 4 and above, you could just use

```
Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", monsters));
```